# How to install mkclean?

Tags: unix, matroska, gnu

Download the tar file from this link .

`> wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/matroska/files/mkvalidator/mkvalidator-0.5.2.tar.bz2/download`

Unzip the archive with tar.

`> tar -xjf ./download`

I access the directory.

`> ./mkvalidator-0.5-2`

I execute the shell script.

```
> ./configure
: not found: 2: ./configure:
: No such file or directory.  Stop.
mv: cannot stat 'corec/tools/coremake/coremake': No such file or directory
: not found: 6: ./configure:
Running ./coremake gcc_linux_x64
.build' build file not found!r-0.5.2/corec/tools/coremake/gcc_linux_x64
: not found: 9: ./configure:
Now you can run make -C mkvalidator or gmake -C mkvalidator
```

And I get the following result.

I don't know how to go on.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is simple, I found them fiddling a little.

The error is that you have to execute the shell script ./configure file that is inside the mkvalidator or mkclean folder, outside it.

```
> ./mkvalidator-0.5-2
❯ ./mkvalidator/configure
./mkvalidator/configure: 2: ./mkvalidator/configure: %%BEGIN: not found
./mkvalidator/configure: 3: ./mkvalidator/configure: SCRIPT: not found
./mkvalidator/configure: 4: ./mkvalidator/configure: %%END: not found
mv: cannot stat 'corec/tools/coremake/coremake': No such file or directory
Running ./coremake gcc_linux_x64
Now you can run make -C %(PROJECT_NAME) or gmake -C %(PROJECT_NAME)
```

And I get the following result.

Then execute the instructions given by the result of the previous script.

```
> make -C mkvalidator
```

Finally, to add the compiled executables to the path, just add the following lines to your ~ / .bashrc or ~ / .zshrc

```
export MKVALIDATOR="$HOME/mkvalidator/release/gcc_linux_x64"
export PATH="$MKVALIDATOR:$PATH"
```

```
> source ~/.bashrc
> mkvalidator
mkvalidator v0.5.2, Copyright (c) 2010-2015 Matroska Foundation
ERR001: Usage: mkvalidator [options] <matroska_src>
Options:
  --no-warn   only output errors, no warnings
  --live      only output errors/warnings relevant to live streams
  --details   show details for valid files
  --divx      assume the file is using DivX specific extensions
  --quick     exit after the first error or warning
  --quiet     don't ouput progress and file info
  --version   show the version of mkvalidator
  --help      show this screen
        file ""
```